# The aggregation output disappeared but the database size was doubled

Tags: mongodb

The aggregation output is disappear.

I ran a aggregation task.

It should write the result to another collection.

The data size is really large, about **1TB**

Now, I checked the DB status, it show me the current DB size is **2TB**

And the `tmp.agg_out.1` is not exsisting anymore, so the task is supposely done

```
tw_weather  2296.832GB
```

somehow the output collection's count is **ZERO**

```
> db.result.count()
0
```

Where is the result ? If there is no output, why the DB size is doubled ?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1105 mongodb   20   0  4.495t 9.368g 771684 S   0.3 63.8 488:26.99 mongod
```

Is there anyway to let me know what's going on now ?

```
~$ mongostat
insert query update delete getmore command flushes  mapped   vsize  res faults idx miss % qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 2296.9G 4602.7G 9.4G      0          0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    2 02:41:29
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 2296.9G 4602.7G 9.4G      0          0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    2 02:41:30
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 2296.9G 4602.7G 9.4G      0          0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    2 02:41:31
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 2296.9G 4602.7G 9.4G      0          0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    2 02:41:32


~$ mongotop
2015-05-08T02:42:37.117+0000    connected to: 127.0.0.1

                                              ns    total    read    write    2015-05-08T02:42:38Z
                              admin.system.roles      0ms     0ms      0ms
                            admin.system.version      0ms     0ms      0ms
                               local.startup_log      0ms     0ms      0ms
                            local.system.indexes      0ms     0ms      0ms
                         local.system.namespaces      0ms     0ms      0ms
                            local.system.replset      0ms     0ms      0ms
           weather.cds      0ms     0ms      0ms
 weather.import_errors      0ms     0ms      0ms
      weather.result      0ms     0ms      0ms
weather.system.indexes      0ms     0ms      0ms
```

## Here is the aggregate snippet

It works on sample data (about 10million but failed on whole data about 1billion size)

```
source_collection = "cds"
output_collection = "result"
db[output_collection].drop()
db[output_collection].createIndex({symptom_history:1});
pipeline = [
    { "$project": {
        "doc": "$$ROOT",
        "id": "$$ROOT.ID",
        "weathers": "$$ROOT.weathers"
    }},
    {"$unwind": '$weathers'},
    {"$group":{'_id': "$id",
              'records': {'$push': '$doc'},
              'weather_history': {'$addToSet': '$weathers'},
              'count': {"$sum": 1}
              }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "id": "$id",
            "weather_history": "$weather_history",
            "count": "$count",
            "records": "$records",
        }
    },
    { "$out" : output_collection }
]

cur = db[source_collection].runCommand('aggregate',
    {pipeline: pipeline,allowDiskUse: true})
```

Comment: You can use `mongostat` and `mongotop` services to debug further

Comment: Could you include the code of the aggregation task, please?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru Hi I update it